# Whats wrong in using the words Whilst and Due to?

Tags: sentence, writing-style, style-manuals

I remember reading in an English style guide ([The Scott Foresman Handbook for Writers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132370034)) that the words *`whilst`* and *`due to`* were quite redundant and not to be used. The author did not seem to like them as whilst was just another word for while and `due to` was a rough form of saying *because*.

However, I've found myself using the *due to* quite often. For instance, I'm writing a long sentence that can have two `because`s. In that case I end up using *due to* in place of the second *because*. For example:

> For a sincere and talented writer, all barriers to entry are finally removed **because** of the e-publishing phenomena, and that was only possible **due to** the Internet revolution pioneered by Tim Berners Lee in the early nineties.

What can I use in place of second because if I don't want to use `due to`?

Also, I personally find it more elegant to say "Whilst" instead of "While". But is that the perception of most modern readers or not?

Comment: Whilst I have come across denigration of its use, I employ 'whilst' all of the time, and to the meagre extent to which I pay attention to it, others do too. I've never encountered disapproval of the phrase 'due to', and find the idea that it's redundant, as it clearly conveys causation. A word isn't redundant just because it has a synonym; it's redundant when its meaning is already conveyed through other words in the sentence.

Comment: 'Whilst' is an archaic and outdated form of 'while'. That it is somehow more formal or more elegant is a common misconception. Common enough, perhaps, that certain demographics of reader would prefer the former. The same is true of 'amongst' and 'among'.

Comment: @mike32 What committee determines when such things are archaic? And where can I obtain a memorandum of their utterances over the last several years? Of whom are they composed, and how do they arrive at their decisions?

Comment: @WS2 To not answer your question, 'whilst' is archaic in American English ( that's not a value judgement just an observation). It may very well be common in other varieties. Also, language use may be prescribed by some committees but people will say new things regardless.

Comment: @Mitch Well I speak one of the 'other varieties', perhaps one of the more obscure ones, namely the English of England.

Comment: @WS2 Chapeau! And I presume that you use 'whilst'? SO it's archaic to us and not to you, that's language. Who is it that still use 'thou' and 'thee'? Archaic to us but not to them. I' sure there are all sort of things that sound archaic to you that Americans still use.

Comment: @WS2 Academic and professional establishments maintain style guides that may class such things as archaic. A cursory Internet search informs me that disapproval of 'whilst' ('amidst', 'amongst', etc.) is more prevalent in American and Canadian English, so I can understand your disagreement. My personal British English experience has been to avoid such terms as per style guides and advice from lecturers where I have studied. If I had had the time to establish some citations my statement would have been an answer, not a comment.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "due to", if it's not overused.  Especially in situations where you want to avoid over-becausing, it may be a good choice.  (But in your e-publishing sentence above, I'd actually prefer to see "due to" and "because of" swapped.)  "Whilst" is archaic, but may be appropriate in "poetic" contexts.

Comment: And Mr. Foresman is definitely wrong on one point:  "Due to" is not an alternative form of "because", it's an alternative form of "because of", a phrase that is considerably longer and harder to pronounce.

Comment: @HotLicks You speak with such remarkable confidence and authority when you declare the word to be 'archaic'. Does it mean there is a law against using it? Or if I should have the temerity to use it would it thus determine that I was 'archaic' too. And what might be the penalty for that?

Comment: @HotLicks Could all this declaring of words archaic, be due to the fact that English, as it exists, is too difficult for some people. Perhaps there should be a special category established, known as *Simple English* so that those who find the whole language too difficult could just take more limited exams at school.

Comment: @WS2 - I use "archaic" to simply mean "old style, and no longer in common use."  (And I consider that it covers a spectrum from simply out of style to so old as to be incomprehensible.)  There probably is a better term, but being somewhat archaic myself, I'm certainly not saying that "whilst" should never be used.

Comment: @HotLicks Personally I would love to be able to speak as Shakespeare wrote. Rather than render words redundant we should be seeking to reinstate earlier forms of the language. I know someone who belongs to a club which arranges weekends, usually in historic hotels, where participants speak 16th-century English with one another.

Comment: @WS2 - I'd just like to be able to buy a new Windows Vista laptop and not have to muck with this Windows 8 carp.  But I can't make time stand still.  It's nice to have an appreciation (or even a preference) for antiques, but we have to live in the "modern" world, whether we like it or not.

Comment: @HotLicks What you say is true of Technology, but not of Linguistics. As someone who does programming for a living, I've found that Technology *evolves* over time, while Language elegance *degrades* over time. C# is certainly  better than Java, and Java is better than C++ in terms of features. However, I find Sanskrit to be better than Hindi, and Latin better than English in terms of poetic elegance!

Comment: @Hot Licks: Whilst I agree with your "old style, and no longer in common use" classification (in ***AmE***, certainly not in ***BrE***), I think even on your side of the pond it would be better to call it ***dated***. And British English is simply too widely established to lump it in with limited-currency ***dialectal*** usages such as "thou" in Amish or Northern British "regional" speech.

Comment: @HotLicks But because it is a 'modern world' doesn't mean it has to be a simplified 'dumbed-down' world. That is the problem with the way that much of English progresses. Technology dumbs down life, so that people lose the skills their parents and grandparents had. That is fine when it come to making porridge in a microwave, so you don't have to do it on the stove. But the principle of 'simplification' gets applied to things like language. If it carries on like this we shall end up as a race of simpletons.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Yeah, if the term had come to mind I would have said "dated" instead.

Comment: @PrahladYeri - But C.A.R. Hoare said of Algol 60  "Here is a language so far ahead of its time that it was not only an improvement on its predecessors but also on nearly all its successors."  I can tell you that much of technology *does* degrade over time, having been a computer engineer/programmer for 45 years.

Comment: @Prahlad Yeri: Many people yearn for "the good old days", but let's be realistic. Language evolves to meet the *communication* needs (and *preferences*) of current speakers. You can bewail the fact that we don't speak/write like the people of Shakespeare's day, but the reality is if you started doing that you'd only be an interesting novelty for a very short time (before people got *seriously* fed up with you! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers ***Light, seeking light, doth light of light beguile;*** :-) Unfortunately, Yes. But the least we can do is preserve our interest and keep learning as much of the *old stuff* as we learn the *new stuff*.

Comment: @HotLicks Cobol was much before my time, but the general consensus is that writing programs have become much easier now with *garbage-collected* languages like Java and C# that does a lot of dirty work (like `memory management`) on the programmer's behalf. Also, there are now IDEs with syntax highlighting such as Eclipse/VisualStudio that were certainly missing during the Algol/Cobol era.

Comment: @PrahladYeri - To a significant extent things like garbage collection (which was far from original with Java) simply allow programs to grow more complex and unwieldy even faster.  And I know that many of the new features added to Java have not actually improved its functionality but simply made it harder to understand and manage.  (I call it "C++ envy".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"For a sincere and talented writer, all barriers to entry are finally removed because of the e-publishing phenomena, and that was only possible due to the Internet revolution pioneered by Tim Berners Lee in the early nineties" sounds OK to me (bear in mind that I am not a native speaker though).

Moreover, if, as you asked, wanted to know what can you use in place of second because if you don't want to use due to, I would suggest **[thanks to](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/thanks+to)** ;

" For a sincere and talented writer, all barriers to entry are finally removed because of the e-publishing phenomena **thanks to** Internet revolution pioneered by Tim Berners Lee in the early nineties"

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of good reasons not to use "whilst":

1. It is identical to "while" in meaning, but because it's a rarer word, it distracts your reader.
2. It has never been the norm. Dickens never uses it, and even Shakespeare uses it sparingly.
3. Many style guides, including the BBC, the Guardian, the Economist, and the Canadian Hansard, advise simply to replace it with "while".
4. It sounds pompous and affected.

"Due to" is fine the way you use it: it might be a bit of a writer's disease to avoid duplicating formulations, but if you can do it without jumping through hoops, it does make your prose sound more elegant, and "due to" is clear and understandable.